# Как с помощью ffmpeg делать четкие не черные скриншоты с видео в автоматическом режиме

Tags: screenshots, видео, ffmpeg

То есть суть вопроса в том, чтобы автоматически делать качественный скриншот с видео с помощью ffmpeg.
Под качественным я имею ввиду не размытый и не одного цвета (то есть в кадре должно что-то быть) скриншот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто (с указанием какого то параметра не получится)

Но можно сделать так:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mpg -r 1 -t 00:05:00 images%05d.png
```

Для каждой секунды видео будет создан скриншот, на протяжении 5ти минут.

В итоге у нас будет куча файликов. Анализируя каждый ищем чтото отличное от черного екрана. И получаем заветный скриншот. Как то так..

Comment: Использовать GD библиотеку с PHP для анализа скрина нормально?

Answer (score 1):

Я сделал так: делаю скриншот, смотрю его размер, если меньше 2кб, значит там какой-то монотонный цвет, делаю скриншот с шагом в 5 секунд.